# Flow chart how to determine which low code platform to use?

Tags: salesforce, camunda, outsystems, mendix, appian

[Low code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-code_development_platform) is getting somehow much attention recently, and I am looking for hard, fact-based decision criteria for which platform to choose for which purpose or industry.

I found a [flow chart at stackify](https://stackify.com/low-code-dev-platform/) compiled by Ben Putano in 2017 which is a step in the right direction:
[image: Flow chart to choose low code platform]

The chart references only [Appian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appian_Corporation), [outsystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OutSystems), [kony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kony,_Inc.), [mendix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mendix), agile point, [caspio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caspio), [salesforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salesforce), [PowerBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Power_BI), but does not talk about platforms like. [LabView](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LabVIEW), [UiPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UiPath), [Pega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasystems), [Camunda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camunda), [Blue Prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Prism).

I would appreciate some theoretical, scientific input on the whole story of low-code and how to classify the different platforms.

Comment: I also struggle to find common features in the quoted flow chart: Why are some [CRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management) in the list, and others not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've built no-code platforms classification based on these 4 questions:

1. What are the skills your team is good at? (Sales, design, product management, programming, etc).
2. What is your app front-end? (Responsive web app, native mobile app, static website, API, chatbot, etc).
3. Type of app you want to build? (Dashboard, directory, marketplace, communication app, community, social network, CRM/ERP, etc).
4. Do you plan to accept payments? (Yes/No).

We use this classification in our no-code tools advisor service: https://www.nocodesetup.com

Based on its performance, we see that ~80% of people finish such survey to get a personalized recommendation about the right no-code tools to build their app.

To choose the right low-code/no-code platform, other questions might be very useful too. But the more questions you add, the more chances people will get stuck answering them.

Another great example of no-code platforms classification by Aron Korenblit (Head of education at airtable.com): http://read.aatt.io/issues/no-code-is-not-a-monolith-207566

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's much more complex than this, I believe.

There are so many platforms equally capable of getting you the results you need. A thorough evaluation is still needed. At the low-code company I work at, we felt this as a common pain point for lots of prospects - evaluating low-code vendors, which made us create [this scorecard](https://www.dronahq.com/low-code-evaluation-tool/) where you can assess ANY low-code/no-code vendor to find the best fit for your use case.

You can use the tool to find which platform is the right fit!